# ASP.Net Jquery Calender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I needed to add a calender control in a ASP Grid View. As the ASP.Net grid view is not collapsible I have tried the jquery calender. By referencing to the [enter link description here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/jquery-ui-datepickercalendar-example-in.html)

Although this works when the server tags are placed in a form tag when I add this to a page which inherited from a master page and with ASP MainContentPlaceHolder's the calender does not get triggered.

[image]

Please share me what I am doing wrong as the drop down with the calender does not shown.

Comment: You should just copy paste your code here using the code block instead of  placing an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id of your textbox is changed by ASP.net.

You can either set a static ID so the client Id will be the same as the server ID:

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" />
```

Or put a class on the textbox like `txtCalendar`, and use the class when creating the calendar in jquery:

```
$('.txtCalendar').datepicker();
...
<asp:Textbox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="txtCalendar" />
```